# How to identify message of finish when click a button with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I have to execute a sequence of buttons with selenium, there are diferents take different minuts, Then I need to identify when finish the process of the button, this show a panel with a message "Ha concluido la ejecución..."

1. When click on button show

[image]

1. When process finish show.

[image]

I have a control:

span_control = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span[class='status-execution-process']")
text_value = span_control.text

text_value could be values 0, 1, 2

0 when no execute button
2 while are executing button
1 when finish button executed

How to do something that while text_value is equal to 2, continue in a while, but when is text_value es equal to 1, finish this while.

Comment: Post the URL, we cannot suggest any solution without that, and also post the code you've tried.

Comment: @AbiSaran I update  whit code, I want to do a while that validate every 5 seconds if a text value change